# user/USER_ID/lists endpoint not returning all my lists

Tags: foursquare

The user/USER_ID/lists endpoint seems to only be returning 4 of my lists instead of all of them. I have created 5 lists (well, including the TODO list I have 5) and that endpoint is only returning the 4 more recently updated lists. All my lists show up on the foursquare website for both my profile and when I click the save button, but when I use the endpoint in my app or in the explorer I only get 4 lists. As a test I added a venue to the list that wasn't showing up and now that list is returned but another list is no longer being returned. The count attribute shows 5, but the items array only contains 4.

Comment: You'll need to post more information about the request you're making to the api, (though be sure to remove your access token)

Comment: I was calling the endpoint without a group, once I added group=created it returned everything. I'd thought I'd had added that before but there were 2 places I was calling this endpoint, did it for one but not the other.

Comment: Hey Gilbert, mind posting your comment as an answer, so people know it's been resolved? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was calling the endpoint without a group, once I added group=created it returned everything. I'd thought I'd had added that before but there were 2 places I was calling this endpoint, did it for one but not the other.